# how to call flutter function that is inside stateful widget in outside function?

Tags: flutter, stateful

I want to call the _setSilentMode() function inside fireAlarm().
_setSilentMode() is inside statefull widget but fireAlarm() is outside stateful widget. whenever i put _setSilentMode() function inside fireAlarm() it gives error.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 
  Future<void> _setSilentMode() async {
    RingerModeStatus status;

    try {
      status = await SoundMode.setSoundMode(RingerModeStatus.silent);

      setState(() {
        _soundMode = status;
      });
    } on PlatformException {
      print('Do Not Disturb access permissions required!');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              Switch(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    isOn = value;
                  });

                  AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
                    Duration(seconds: 15),
                    alarmId,
                    fireAlarm,
                  );
                  print('Alarm set  at ${DateTime.now()}');
                },
                value: isOn,
                activeColor: Colors.blue,
                activeTrackColor: Colors.yellow,
                inactiveThumbColor: Colors.redAccent,
                inactiveTrackColor: Colors.orange,
              )
            ],
          ))),
    );
  }
}

 void fireAlarm() {
    print('Alarm Fired at ${DateTime.now()}');
      // i want to call _setSilentMode() here but it gives me error 
     _setSilentMode();
 }
```

please help me that how to solve this problem and add _setSilentMode() inside fireAlarm() to work.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use GlobalKey to access the State and call method of state to update UI. You need to make state and method public.
- Alternatively, I recommend using state management libraries such as RiverPod or Provider.

Answer (score 0):

The method is outside the State class. For such you simply add widget before calling it

```
widget.fireAlarm
```

Comment: there is no problem in fireAlarm function but the problem is that i cannot add _setSilentMode() inside fireAlarm fuction because it gives an error.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why both your functions are on different logical levels? If not then you can move them in the same level so that calling them is easier, wither in the Widget or in the State classes. If you move fireAlarm() just below _setSilentMode, your code should still work just fine

Comment: if i move the fireAlarm() below the _setSilentMode() then the fireAlarm doesnt called.